# How to better structure Jasmine unit tests such that they don't end up in a huge file?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, components

I want to make sure my unit tests are readable and maintainable, rather than dump all tests for my component (or class) in one file as it seems to be the "best practice" right now. I think this practice is detrimental for anything but trivial code or components and it can become a negative force in all JS / TS codebases I've seen.

Not being a frontend developer myself I'm struggling to find or see a better alternative, but so far the only option that fixes "fat test file" problem is creating a `specs` folder for each component / service and:

- create one test file per method

or

- create one test file per describe "context"

When common state or setup is needed, I can create a "helper" service or some other common functionality that can be called from the tests that need it.

Is this something considered an acceptable approach or is this question still not really established in terms of best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Take the issue in the other way : **why are your tests so heavy ?**

As per [the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility), you should consider limiting your files to 400 lines of codes.

Removing the boilerplate, imports and spaces, that equates to roughly 300 lines of code. Are your ng features being limited to that ?

As stated in the link, you should rely on the rule of one, which basically states that your features should have a single responsibility. Do your features follow that rule ?

Besides that, assuming you're following those rules and still have massive testing files, there are several solutions to reduce the amount of code required to test :

- For the mocks, you can create a separate file in the same folder of your ng feature
- You can split your tests in several files, each one being dedicated to a specific task (`***.ui.spec.ts`, `***.http.spec.ts` ...)
- You can also factorize your testing code in classes/constants, to make it reusable

And finally,

> but so far the only option that fixes "fat test file" problem is creating a specs folder for each component / service

Is wrong. As per the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules),

> To work efficiently you must be able to find files quickly, especially when you do not know (or do not remember) the file names. Keeping related files near each other in an intuitive location saves time. A descriptive folder structure makes a world of difference to you and the people who come after you

Si you should keep the test files next to their feature.

Comment: Thanks, but your last quote directly contradicts your proposal and supports mine. A spec file is (1) descriptive and (2) keeps related files together and (3) clusters related files in an intuitive location. If you need to also include mock files, then that's an even stronger argument for a spec folder isn't it? Otherwise you'll end up with a .ts / .html / .scss files for your component, plus 10 files for your tests and mocks.

Comment: I certainly like splitting files by task and I need to explore that. In general almost every single jasmine test I've seen (and I even looked on github at _many_ random spec files in Angular projects) is a total disaster in terms of principles (such as SOLID) but especially in terms of size and readability. Why that happens I don't know, and I don't think there is one reason for all cases. It's probably a combination of a general lack of experience with (frontend) unit testing and the tool (Jasmine) that _appears_ awkward and verbose to use for anything but the most trivial test cases.

Comment: ... And of course bad component design, which leads to many tests required for that component. But again even for some relatively simple components you can end up with big test files that are hard to navigate.

Comment: @Rombix you can create a spec folder **in the same** folder if you want, but I didn't get that from your comment, what I got was that you had a spec folder like you have a `src` folder, am I mistaken ?

Comment: Oh I see now! Yes, I meant in the same folder as the component, not a separate project-wide spec folder. We're on the same page.

Comment: @Rombix oh okay then, well yeah there's no issue in that ! It respects LIFT so you're good (as far as I'm concerned, obviously). But even if we're on the same page, the first point stands : check your features code, and try to split it to reduce the amount of code to test !